# How can i alert if the input is not enough after submit with jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, input, count

I have a form and want to sum all persons which where entered and alert something like: "thats not enough what you have entered" after submit. The minimum sum must be 10, if there not enough people the form will not be sent. I've tried something like:

```
jQuery(function($){
    //if submit button is clicked
    $('#submit').click(function () {  
        var $form = $('#booking'),
        $summands = $form.find('.persons'),
        $form.delegate('.persons', 'change', function() {
            var sum = 0;
            $summands.each(function() {
                var value = Number($(this).val());
                if (!isNaN(value)) 
                    sum += value;
            });
            alert( " + sum + " );
        });
    else {
        send email or something
    }
```

Could someone give me a hint please?

Thank you

Comment: use any `div` default make it hide and if goes to else condition then remove css class for it.

Comment: First thing you need to do is to write `$form.delegate('.persons', 'change', function ()` event handler outside `$('#submit').click(function () {`

Comment: `.delegate()` has been deprecated in newer versions of jQuery: please use `.on()` instead. Also, to prevent the form submitting by default, you should use `e.preventDefault()`. Moreover, you should avoid binding events within event handlers, unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: This might help you in understanding the availability of various event handlers : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/601117/jQuery-attach-remove-an-event-handler-function